# Show Ax(BUC) = (AxB)U(AxC) and ¬(A∧B) <=> ¬Av¬B

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let A,B and C be a set show

Ax(B U C) = (AxB) U (AxC)

I really do not understand what to do here. I mean you just have to use distributive law. 
My solution would be:

Ax(BUC) = (AxB)U(AxC) | on the left hand side one has to use distr. law

(AxB)U(AxC) = (AxB)U(AxC) q.e.d

Is this really enough?

Another example regarding logic

Show

¬(A∧B) <=> ¬Av¬B

by using trough tables but you do not need truth tables..
My solution would be:

¬(A∧B) <=> ¬Av¬B | on the left hand side use the law by De Morgan

¬Av¬B  <=> ¬Av¬B  q.e.d

Here you just would not need truth tables but I just could draw one.

But are the solutions enough? This was only the first exercise sheet. Maybe because of that you just do not have write a lot?

Comment: Regarding the logical part, using [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Formal_notation) gives you a one-line proof, and thus it is enough, if you are allowed to use it.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I have answered below. For the future: you should ask just one question per posting, provide enough context so we can know what tools you are allowed to use, and format mathematics with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you guys, and for format mathematics I will use it in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument isn't right. It's circular. You have to prove that the distributive law is valid for these set operations. To do that, go back to the definitions of the operations and the fact that two sets are equal just when they contain the same elements.

I suspect that the second argument is circular too, in this context. I think you have been asked to prove de Morgan's law using truth tables, so you can't just invoke it in your argument.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will mark it in 2 minutes.